# Как сделать в span маску?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть некоторый span(вот ниже), я его заполняю через jquery, можно ли определять вид его по маске, типо если маска xxx-xxx, то текст будет:156-512?

```
<span id="num-g1"></span>
```

$("#num-g1").text("156512");

Comment: а как именно вы маску задаете?

Comment: @ThisMan, Я вот и хотел спросить как сделать. Мне кажется в span записать доп. параметры

Comment: ну вот написали вы маску `xxx-xxx-x`, а что если я запишу туда больше 7 сивмолов, что должно произойти? обрезаться?

Comment: @ThisMan, да обрезаться, а если меньше то просто свободное место

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const $input = $('#num');
const $result = $('#result');

const formatByMask = (mask, value) => {
  let formattedValue = mask;
  const maskCharCount = [...mask].reduce((result, chr) => {
    if(chr === 'X') result++;
    return result
  }, 0);
  
  for(let i = 0; i < maskCharCount; i++) {
    if(value[i]) formattedValue = formattedValue.replace('X', value[i]);
  }
  
  return formattedValue;
}

$input.on('input', e => {
  const {target} = e;
  const {value} = target;
  const mask = $result.attr('data-mask');
  
  $result.text(formatByMask(mask, value));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='num'>
<div id='result' data-mask='X-XX-XX-X'></div>
```